# Spring Boot GzipResourceResolver with IE 11 not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot based application and my resource handler registry is configured as below

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:static/")
            .setCachePeriod(365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
            .resourceChain(true)

            .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver()
                            .addFixedVersionStrategy("dev", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.map")
                            .addContentVersionStrategy("/**")
                        )

            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer())
            .addTransformer(new AppCacheManifestTransformer());
```

I have a js file named app.min.js and on the same folder there is also a app.min.js.gz file available.

When accessed from Chrome (v43) the GZ file is served correctly.

But, when accessed from IE 11, though the request header has an accept-encoding of "gzip,deflate", the application still sends a .min.js file instead of .min.js.gz file.

Any idea on why this error would occur?

Thanks!

Comment: could you copy/paste the exact request/response headers here? how do you know that the correct/incorrect resource is served: file name, response headers, debug? In doubt, you should open a JIRA issue here: https://jira.spring.io with all the information I requested. Thanks!